# My header keeps disapearing

Tags: jquery, html, css

To put it simply, Im using a fade-in for my website's header text. However the problem I face is that after refreshing the page, the text disapears, and the header shrinks to a tiny sliver at the very top. heres my code:

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#fade").fadeIn(2000);
});
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://bdpastudents.com/~t4645202/dream/dream.css">

<div id="head">
<div id="fade">

<b><h1>Welcome to Dream!</h1></b>
</div>


</div>
</html>
```

And this is my css:

```
#fade { 
display: none; 
}

#head {
background: -moz-radial-gradient(green, white);
text-align: center;
color: white;
padding: 5px;
margin: 0px;
}

body {
margin: 0px; 
}
```

not quite sure whats wrong espically since when you first look at the website it works, but every time after that it doesnt.

Thanks.

Comment: Side note, `<b>` elements can't contain `<h1>` elements.

Comment: I can not see `<head>` and `<body>` tags - where are they?

Comment: You are setting your style sheet after the jQuery runs. Try to load it prior to your jQuery. i can not think of anything else off hand that would cause this behavior, as it is bound to document.,ready so should behave the same every time.

Comment: Thanks Casey! That turned out to be the problem! I simply set the style sheet link above the jquery and now it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

u are missing some tags no?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#fade").fadeIn(2000);
});
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://bdpastudents.com/~t4645202/dream/dream.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="head">
<div id="fade">

<b><h1>Welcome to Dream!</h1></b>
</div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: well, technically no as this is a webpage that will be displayed on another webpage. The body attribute in the css refers to the actual page that this page will be on.

Answer (score 0):

It’s hard to tell what the issue is from the code snippet above, but I would suggest using a different method to fade in the header that’s more accessible and preserves the space it will eventually take up, preventing a relayout.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/vaqome/edit?html,css,js,output

It’s based on these styles:

```
$fade-speed: 2s;

.fade-out {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s linear $fade-speed, opacity $fade-speed;
  visibility: hidden;

}

.fade-in {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: visibility 0s linear 0s, opacity $fade-speed;
}
```

Source: https://medium.com/medium-eng/five-goofy-things-medium-did-that-break-accessibility-3bc804ae818d#940c

Answer (score 0):

[Check this](https://jsfiddle.net/3oms1c8h/)

It works as expected, your problem is not the head, it is the background property you have on it, on the test I changed it for a solid color and works fine.

Check for this rule.. it is not cross browsing

```
background: -moz-radial-gradient(green, white);
```

Answer (score 0):

*Casey* found the problem. The style sheet was set below the jquery, so I simply moved it back to the top. Thanks!